# Efficient C# byte queue for parsing stream of bytes for binary message packets

Tags: c#, data-structures, queue, buffer

I'm trying to replace what I would usually implement as a circular-buffer+.  The function of the queue is to buffer incoming bytes (eg. from serial port or some other stream of data), whilst a parser examines bytes in the queue and detects and extracts message packets.

Criteria:

- can grow (ie not fixed-sized)
- > = 1 bytes can be enqueued at a time
- > = 1 bytes can be dequeued at a time
- efficient

I'm tempted just to use

```
System.Collections.Generic.Queue<byte>
```

... but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient type to use.  Any suggestions?

Are there any smarter ways of doing what I'm trying to do?  (Eg. Interesting suggestions [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32365893/buffering-tcpip-data.aspx))

Thanks for your suggestions & input.

Prembo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Queue<byte>` is backed by a `byte[]`, but you would see better performance if copying to/from the underlying buffer using `Array.Copy` rather than looping through Enqueue/Dequeue methods.  So personally, if `Queue<byte>` doesn't give you the performance you want, then you might implement your own queue class that provides QueueMultiple and DequeueMultiple methods.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `Queue<byte>` will be efficient in terms of memory. It will basically be a `byte[]` behind the scenes. It may be slightly awkward to work with if you want to dequeue or enqueue whole chunks at a time though. Each operation should be amortized O(1) for a single byte, leading to O(n) to enqueue or dequeue a chunk of size n... but the scaling factor will be higher than (say) a buffer block copy.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon how the incoming bytes are received and how the parser examines them, you might consider a `Queue<byte[]>`.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm not be helpful, but you can write one of your own.
The theoretic part:
The queue should be in `byte[]` and 2 indexes, 1 for head and 1 for tail

```
0                                                    n
|----------------------------------------------------|
               |                        |
              head                     tail
```

Each time you need to add `k` bytes you move tail `k` units left and put the in the new space created data there.

```
0                                                    n
|-------------------------------new data-------------|
               |                |       |
              head         new tail  old tail
```

Each time you need to pop `k` bytes you move head `k` units left and take data from the space lost.

```
0                                                    n
|-------new data-------------------------------------|
       |       |                        |
   new head   head                     tail
```

In case head and tail collide, you need to double the size of the container and copy each half to the new one.

Keep in mind: if you add `1234` and then pop 2 letters you will get `34`

(I don't know if I should mark this post as community wiki)

Comment: Generally people don't mark their answers as community wiki.  If the question is community wiki, then the answers will be community wiki too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's **[an efficient implementation](https://github.com/Kelindar/circular-buffer/blob/master/Source/ByteQueue.cs)** of a buffer I wrote a while ago:

- **Resizeable**: allowing to queue up data and not throw buffer overflow exception;
- **Efficient**: uses a single buffer and Buffer.Copy operations to enqueue/dequeue data

Comment: Hi @Kel, how would I return the actual bytes Dequeued from your implementation and store them in an array for conversion to a char array? Thanks.